# Is it typical for walls to vibrate with a suspended whole house fan?

Tags: fans, vibration

Recently had a quiet cool whole house fan installed and notice the walls below the area where the fan was "suspended" seem to vibrate when the fan is running, either on high or low.  Is this typical or expected?  Or is this an indication of the whole house fan not suspended correctly?  Should  there be vibration in the walls at all if the fan is suspended from the attic rafters correctly?

Comment: Well, the attic rafters _connect_ to the walls, so that's expected if the unit isn't properly isolated. Rigid suspension doesn't do much to dampen vibration. Are there isolating mechanisms in the suspension hardware? Please revise to provide more detail. Your question is too broad.

Comment: Could be typical if the walls are poorly constructed.

Comment: Either the fan is not balanced, or it's not installed properly or your house construction is not so hot.  I have never had these issues in any of my houses for the last 40 years.

Comment: every one i've seen makes the walls vibrate some, the question is how much, and related, how much is too much? you might be able to reduce it by notching the heavier blades so that it's better balanced; find the light blades first with a binder clip on a random blade, then play better or worse? Use a phone app noise meter to gauge it. Once you find the light blade side, remove the clip and notch the opposite side a bit at a time with a dremel or file. repeat as needed until it's as quiet as can be reasonably made.